# How can I force a form action to use an absolute URL?

Tags: html

I am using the following form on my website staticmantest.github.io:

`<form class="js-form form" method="post" action="104.131.76.120:8080/v2/entry/StaticManTest/StaticManTest.github.io/master/reviews">`

I intend a `POST` request to be sent to `104.131.76.120:8080/v2/entry/StaticManTest/StaticManTest.github.io/master/reviews`.  However, instead it is being sent to `https://staticmantest.github.io/104.131.76.120:8080/v2/entry/StaticManTest/StaticManTest.github.io/master/reviews`.  What can I do to force this form action to be an absolute path?

Comment: add `http://` before IP address

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prefix you URL with

```
http://
```

so that it's

```
http://104.131.76.120:8080/v2/entry/StaticManTest/StaticManTest.github.io/master/reviews
```

Otherwise it's treated as a relative URL.